# Where is the Insert mode command Control-Shift-U documented in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Insert mode `C-S-U` (control-shift-u) acts (almost) exactly like `C-V u`. However, I'm not finding where this mapping/function is documented. Aside, is `i_CTRL-S-U` how this keycombo would be represented in Vim's help pages and `<C-S-U>` in a :map command?

I'm using VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jul 26 2017 20:13:43).

Comment: I'm not sure what behavior you're seeing as I'm not sure what `C-V u` does, but I believe the `C-S-U` behavior is documented at `i_ctrl-u`.  I don't think there is a difference between `C-S-U` and `C-u`.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I left the most important part out of the question! They are both a way to input Unicode characters. I think Hans has the right idea, where the former is Vim functionality and the later is provided by the OS or terminal emulator (on mobile so can't check right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-S-U` is not a Vim function: it is for inserting Unicode characters based on their HEX values.

Because it is a functionality of the OS, it is not in the Vim documentation (it's like `C-S-V` for pasting text, which is a function of the terminal and also not documented in Vim).